# Check glibc version for a particular gcc compiler

Tags: c, gcc, glibc

I have two gcc compilers installed on my system, one is `gcc 4.1.2` (default) and the other is `gcc 4.4.4`. How can I check the libc version used by `gcc 4.4.4`, because `/lib/libc.so.6` shows the glibc used by `gcc 4.1.2`, since it is the default compiler.

Comment: If you want to perform the check at compile time, then Zwol's answer below is probably the best method. If you want to check the version at runtime, then R1tschY's answer is probably the best method. Note that you may not get the Glibc version or standard C++ library version you expect at runtime due to Linux's inability to get the paths right on its own. Also see [Linking g++ 4.8 to libstdc++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17220872/608639)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Write a test program (name it for example `glibc-version.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gnu/libc-version.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("GNU libc version: %s\n", gnu_get_libc_version());
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

and compile it with the gcc-4.4 compiler:

```
gcc-4.4 glibc-version.c -o glibc-version
```

When you execute `./glibc-version` the used glibc version is shown.

Comment: it works for me, but where is this docummented? I'm looking [at the glibc 2.7 docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html) but I can't find it.

Comment: The function is part of the Gnulib: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/gnulib.html

Comment: Can you not just put `ldd --version`?

Comment: I use OSX and I am getting ==> fatal error: 'gnu/libc-version.h' file not found <== Why might this be? Does not osx come with standard c library?

Comment: @KorayTugay:  Well, yes, but OS X/macOS started switching over from GCC to LLVM/Clang (though it _did_ have an instance of LLVM-GCC available for a little while) all the way back with the release of Xcode 3.1, IIRC, so you'd have to look for _Clang's_ C standard library.

Comment: OSX has _never_ used the GNU C Library; its Unix userspace is all BSD-derived.  It did originally use GCC as its system compiler, but Apple as an organization is allergic to the GPLv3; it is not an accident that they started funding LLVM heavily _right_ after GCC's licensing was changed over.

Answer (score 87):

Use `ldd --version`:

```
$ ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
...
```

You can also run libc itself:

```
$ /lib/libc.so.6
GNU C Library (GNU libc) stable release version 2.17, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
...
```

Comment: Results from above commands are not the same. On my computer : GNU libc version: 2.17, ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ??

Comment: That shows what `ldd` was linked with. When linking programs you link with some implementation of `libc` (there can be more than one), not with `ldd`.

Comment: This does not apply for cross compilers though.

Answer (score 39):

Use `-print-file-name` `gcc` option:

```
$ gcc -print-file-name=libc.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
```

That gives the path. Let's examine the file:

```
$ file $(gcc -print-file-name=libc.so)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so: ASCII text

$ cat $(gcc -print-file-name=libc.so)
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
GROUP ( /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ) )
```

The file is a linker script, which links the libraries in `GROUP` list.

---

On ELF platforms `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` is a position-independent executable with a dynamic symbol table (like that of a shared library):

```
$ file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: symbolic link to libc-2.31.so

$ file $(readlink -f /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=1878e6b475720c7c51969e69ab2d276fae6d1dee, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

$ /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
GNU C Library (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.9) stable release version 2.31.
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 9.4.0.
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC ABSOLUTE
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bugs>.
```

Answer (score 31):

`gnu_get_libc_version` identifies the *runtime* version of the GNU C Library.

If what you care about is the *compile-time* version (that is, the version that provided the headers in `/usr/include`), you should look at the macros `__GLIBC__` and `__GLIBC_MINOR__`.  These expand to positive integers, and will be defined as a side-effect of including *any* header file provided by the GNU C Library; this means you can include a standard header, and then use `#ifdef __GLIBC__` to decide whether you can include a nonstandard header like `gnu/libc-version.h`.

Expanding the test program from the accepted answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef __GLIBC__
#include <gnu/libc-version.h>
#endif

int
main(void)
{
#ifdef __GLIBC__
  printf("GNU libc compile-time version: %u.%u\n", __GLIBC__, __GLIBC_MINOR__);
  printf("GNU libc runtime version:      %s\n", gnu_get_libc_version());
  return 0;
#else
  puts("Not the GNU C Library");
  return 1;
#endif
}
```

When I compile and run this program on the computer I'm typing this answer on (which is a Mac) it prints

```
Not the GNU C Library
```

but when compiled and run on a nearby Linux box it prints

```
GNU libc compile-time version: 2.24
GNU libc runtime version:      2.24
```

Under normal circumstances, the "runtime" version could be bigger than the "compile-time" version, but never smaller.  The major version number is unlikely ever to change again (the last time it changed was the "libc6 transition" in 1997).

If you would prefer a shell 'one-liner' to dump these macros, use:

```
echo '#include <errno.h>' | gcc -xc - -E -dM | 
    grep -E '^#define __GLIBC(|_MINOR)__ ' | sort
```

The `grep` pattern is chosen to match only the two macros that are relevant, because there are dozens of internal macros named `__GLIBC_somethingorother` that you don't want to have to read through.

Comment: And from comments on a related question: `echo '#include <errno.h>' | gcc -x c -dM -E - | egrep -i '(gnu|lib)'`.

Comment: Uclibc-ng supports `gnu_get_libc_version()`, so "Not the GNU C Library" is not precise.

Comment: @pevik Does it define `__GLIBC__`? (It shouldn't.)

Comment: @zwol Yes, it does: in [features.h](https://cgit.openadk.org/cgi/cgit/uclibc-ng.git/tree/include/features.h#n82), which is used in [gnu/libc-version.h](https://cgit.openadk.org/cgi/cgit/uclibc-ng.git/tree/include/gnu/libc-version.h).

Comment: @pevik I would say that's a bug in uclibc, unless it _already_ supports every single glibc extension, which seems unlikely.

Comment: @zwol IMHO it's not. They define `__GLIBC__   2` and `__GLIBC_MINOR__ 2` in [features.h](https://cgit.openadk.org/cgi/cgit/uclibc-ng.git/tree/include/features.h#n387), which is what they probably fully support. glibc 2.2 was released 2000-11-09 (18 years ago) and if you compare headers from both projects, they look similar.

Comment: @zwol see also https://blogs.gentoo.org/blueness/2016/03/31/why-macros-like-__glibc__-and-__uclibc__-are-bad/

Comment: FTR, in Glibc you can also use a macro `__GLIBC_PREREQ`, like this: `#if __GLIBC_PREREQ(2, 33) …`

Comment: @Hi-Angel Please don't, that is an undocumented macro that might disappear or change behavior with no warning.

Answer (score 11):

I doubt if you have more than one glibc installed in your system.But `ldd -v <path/to/gcc-4.x>` should give you the glibc used.

Comment: `-v` was killer advice in my case and helped me see exactly what library versions were missing.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is to use `ldd` which comes with `glibc`

Just run this command `ldd --version` :

```
dina@dina-X450LA:~$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu9) 2.23
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

Their is two additional ways to find out the glibc version:

1. Check the version of the installed glibc rpm package : this by runing this command

   `rpm -q glibc`
2. Check the version of the used libc.so file. This way is a little bit more difficult. You can check it in this link: [Linux: Check the glibc version](https://benohead.com/linux-check-glibc-version/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use strings command to check GLIBC version of compiler. Highest version is applicable.

```
ubuntu1604:extra$ strings ./arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc | grep GLIBC
    GLIBC_2.3
    GLIBC_2.8
    GLIBC_2.14
    GLIBC_2.4
    GLIBC_2.11
    GLIBC_2.2.5
    GLIBC_2.3.4
```

Comment: Note that this does not really tell you the version. Let's assume that the binary was linked against glibc 2.17, but happened not to reference any symbols with symbol versions later than `GLIBC_2.14`. Then it could easily produce the same list of symbol versions.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check the higher versioning symbol of the libc:

```
readelf -V /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Answer (score 0):

At first do

`ldd` which cat `| grep libc`

to find

`libc.so.6`

If output be for example

`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`

Then run that, which output result will be

```
GNU C Library (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.9) stable release version 2.31.
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 9.4.0.
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC ABSOLUTE
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bugs>.
```