# Which GLIBC version is using my toolchain?

Tags: arm, ld, glibc, toolchain

I know how to check the GNU C Library on my x86 workstation, but now I would like to know which GLIBC version is using my cross toolchain for ARM (I didn't build the toolchain). I cant test the libc.so.6 file of my toolchain's `$PATH` library in my x86 workstation.

Is there some way to know the glibc version without compile a test program and testing in my embedded system? Furthermore, how can I know which PATH library is using by default the GNU linker of my toolchain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check glibc version for a particular gcc compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705660/check-glibc-version-for-a-particular-gcc-compiler)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ldd --version` command to check version, like in [GLIBC version](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-check-glibc-version-263103/).

Comment: But i would like to check the GLIBC version which is using my toolchain, better than check the installed version in my embedded device. Maybe they are using different version.

Comment: @user2119381 Take a look to http://www.thelinuxdaily.com/2010/02/finding-glibc-and-gcc-versions/

Comment: @user2119381 Sure, just to call `ldd` **within** your toolchain, e.g.: `~/install/arm-2012.09/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/bin/ldd --version`

Answer (score 0):

You should call `ldd` from your toolchain:

`/full/path/to/your/toolchain/lib/usr/bin/ldd --version`.