# Can't scan directory in order that files appear

Tags: c, linux, scandir

I'm trying to perform DFS on a folder that can contain sub folders. The goal is to locate all `.txt` files from a directory. I need to find the `.txt` files in the order that DFS finds them and preserve the order of files in a folder.

Currently my code for scanning a directory uses the `scandir()` function:

```
int n = scandir(path, &namelist, NULL, alphasort);
```

This sorts the files in a folder in alphabetical order, which isn't exactly what I want.

Edit: I've tried using opendir() and readdir() but this is accessing files in a seemingly random order.

Comment: Are you programming on Linux?

Comment: If you don't want to sort the files, `scandir()` is probably the wrong tool for the job.  What's wrong with just using `opendir()`, `readdir()`, `closedir()`?

Comment: To use `versionsort` a `#define _GNU_SOURCE` is needed before the `#include <dirent.h>`

Comment: You say "preserve the order of files in a folder" and yet you discuss different ways of sorting the names of the files in the folder.  That's puzzling — which do you want?  Sorted order or 'physical order' in some way?  If you want sorted order, then `scandir()` is a good choice.  If you want 'physical order', it is the wrong choice.  What are you seeking really?  You also mention DFS — depth-first search.  Should you be looking at `nftw()` for the '(new) file tree walk'?  Please clarify your requirements by editing some extra information into the question.

Comment: I apologize for being unclear about this. What I meant to do is iterate through the folder in the order that the files appear. I don't know how to describe this order. I also used opendir() and readdir() but this still accessed the files out of order. Specifically I have folders F1, F2, ... , F10 but it accessed them in the order F4,F1,F5,F10,F,F8,F9,F2,F3,F7

Comment: I believe DFS actually has configurable ordering and some of the available ordering algorithms are somewhat complex.

Comment: @RyanMarr did my answer solve your issue about `versionsort` symbol resolution?

Comment: Please note, @RyanMarr, that I explicitly requested you to edit the extra information into the question.  That's where it belongs.  You can format it.  What do you mean by "the order that the files appear"?  In the output from `ls`?  In the output from `*`?  When you read the names using `readdir()`?  In your GUI file manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [versionsort man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/versionsort)

```
int versionsort(const void *a, const void *b);
```

can be passed as a callback to `scandir()` and is declared in `dirent.h`.

---

### First thing to check: "Feature Test Macro Requirements"

From the same page linked above:

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> `scandir()`, `alphasort()`: _BSD_SOURCE || _SVID_SOURCE
>
> `versionsort()`: _GNU_SOURCE.

These macros need to be defined before `dirent.h` inclusion in order to enable the specific feature.

---

### Second thing to check: glibc version

From the same page linked above:

> **Versions**
>
> `versionsort()` was added to glibc in version 2.1.

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9706054/11336762) to learn how to check your glibc version.

Comment: This is good advice for how to get `versionsort()` declared and so on, but the question also says "preserve the order of files in a folder".  Using either `alphasort()` or `versionsort()` inherently defeats this — the objective must be 'no sort'.  And it is not clear how you can achieve 'no sort'.  It might be feasible to compare the two pointers (as numbers via `uintptr_t`) and guess that the ones earlier in the directory appear before those that come later, but it is anything but certain.  The requirements on `scandir()` that all the allocated memory is freed by `free(namelist)` are severe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I interpreted the question like `versionsort()` was actually what they were looking for. From [here](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-versionsort/): _" [versionsort()] [...] sorts directory entries using strverscmp(3) on the strings (*a)->d_name and (*b)->d_name."_ so that, for example _"jan1 < jan10"_ . Isn't that the typical order of presentation of files? Probably you are right and I should have waited for further clarifications from OP.