# How to fix error or warning in C: "implicit declaration of function ‘inet_aton’; did you mean ‘inet_pton’?"

Tags: c, gcc, glibc, gcc-warning

I am unable to use [`inet_aton()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet.3.html) to convert an ASCII IP address such as `"192.168.0.1"` to a `struct in_addr` address in network byte order because I cannot get my code to compile.

I'm working in this file: [socket__geeksforgeeks_udp_server_GS_edit_GREAT.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/socket__geeksforgeeks_udp_server_GS_edit_GREAT.c)

Here is my build command:

```sh
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c17 \
socket__geeksforgeeks_udp_server_GS_edit_GREAT.c -o bin/server \
-lm && bin/server
```

Here is my command and error output:

```
eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c17 socket__geeksforgeeks_udp_server_GS_edit_GREAT.c -o bin/server -lm && bin/server
socket__geeksforgeeks_udp_server_GS_edit_GREAT.c: In function ‘main’:
socket__geeksforgeeks_udp_server_GS_edit_GREAT.c:159:15: error: implicit declaration of function ‘inet_aton’; did you mean ‘inet_pton’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     retcode = inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &addr_server.sin_addr);
               ^~~~~~~~~
               inet_pton
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

The part I want to fix is:

```
implicit declaration of function ‘inet_aton’; did you mean ‘inet_pton’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
```

I *am* including `arpa/inet.h`, which contains the declaration for `inet_aton()`, at the top of my source file, so I know that is not the problem:

```c
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a bunch of study, I figured it out!

(If you are stumbling upon this question, first ensure you have `#include <arpa/inet.h>` at the top of your file, as already stated in the question.)

It turns out that putting `-std=c17` is *more-restrictive* than just leaving that part off. WithOUT `-std=c17`, the gcc compiler includes many more features which are *not* part of the C standard, including POSIX features, gcc extensions, and special Linux system features. So, using `-std=c17` causes the declaration of `inet_aton()` to get *excluded* from `<arpa/inet.h>`, even though it would otherwise be *included.*

### Here are the various fixes, incl. using `-std=gnu17` vs `-std=c17`:

1. [Not recommended, since this is a hack, not a fix] Remove `-Werror` from the build command so that it compiles with that error as a *warning* instead of as an *error*.
2. Remove `-std=c17` so that you get the extra features provided by gcc instead of being limited to the C standard.
3. [GREAT OPTION] Use the less-restrictive `-std=gnu17` instead of `-std=c17` ([thanks, @ikegami!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71801110/error-or-warning-in-c-implicit-declaration-of-function-inet-aton-did-you-me/71801111?noredirect=1#comment126885019_71801111))
4. [ANOTHER GREAT OPTION] Add `-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE` to your build command to define the macro `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` for your entire program, so that gcc will allow in `inet_aton()` from `<arpa/inet.h>` for you (more on this below). Here is my full build command now:

   ```bash
   gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c17 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE \
   socket__geeksforgeeks_udp_server_GS_edit_GREAT.c -o bin/server \
   -lm && bin/server
   ```
5. [Alternative to the option just above] Add `#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE` to the top of your main source file *before* including *any* headers, so that it is defined before your headers get included, thereby allowing in `inet_aton()` from where you include `<arpa/inet.h>`.
6. [I plan on doing this regardless of which option above I also use] Use the better POSIX `inet_pton()` "internet presentation (textual) to network (binary) format" function (see [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#index-inet_005fpton)) instead of the non-POSIX `inet_aton()` "internet ascii string to network" function (see [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet.3.html)). See more on this below.

Any of those options work. I recommend option 3, 4, or 5, but I prefer 3 the most, and 4 after that. In *all* cases, I plan on *also* implementing option 6, however.

### "Feature test macros" in gcc

How do options 4 and 5 above work? I learned they are part of gcc's "feature test macros" system. Read all about it here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html. In essence, certain features of gnu's glibc library implementation are *excluded* as you include header files unless certain "feature test macros" are defined *before* you include that header.

Go look at the `man` page for `inet_aton()`: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet.3.html. It states at the bottom of the "SYNOPSIS" section at the top of the page:

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see [feature_test_macros(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html)):
>
> `inet_aton()`, `inet_ntoa()`:
>
> - Since glibc 2.19:
>
>   - `_DEFAULT_SOURCE`
> - In glibc up to and including 2.19:
>
>   - `_BSD_SOURCE || _BSD_SOURCE`

So, [check your version of glibc with `ldd --version`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20155150/4561887). Mine shows `2.27`:

```bash
$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.5) 2.27
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

That means the part that says `Since glibc 2.19:` above applies to me, and I must define the "feature test macro" `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` in the source code before including any headers (my option 5 above), *or* in the build command (my option 4 above) to include these features, including `inet_aton()`.

Simply leaving off `-std=c17` also works because the [feature_test_macros man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) (also available at the command-line via `man feature_test_macros`) states:

> Note that, as described below, **some feature test macros are defined by default,** so that it may not always be necessary to explicitly specify the feature test macro(s) shown in the SYNOPSIS.

and:

> #### `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` (since glibc 2.19)
>
> This macro can be defined to ensure that the "default"
> definitions are provided even when the defaults would
> otherwise be disabled, as happens when individual macros
> are explicitly defined, or the compiler is invoked in one
> of its "standard" modes (e.g., `cc -std=c99`).  Defining
> `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` without defining other individual macros
> or invoking the compiler in one of its "standard" modes
> has no effect.
>
> The "default" definitions comprise those required by
> POSIX.1-2008 and ISO C99, as well as various definitions
> originally derived from BSD and System V.  On glibc 2.19
> and earlier, these defaults were approximately equivalent
> to explicitly defining the following:
>
> ```bash
> cc -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_SVID_SOURCE
> -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809
> ```

Notice that it mentions `-std=c99`. That concept applies to my usage of `-std=c17`, so I have to define `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` to counter the feature-removal effect created by `-std=c17`.

### Just use the POSIX-compliant `inet_pton()` instead of the non-POSIX `inet_aton()`

Lastly, an even better option than using the *non*-POSIX function `inet_aton()` ("ASCII string to network" function) is to use the POSIX function `inet_pton()` ("presentation string to network" function).

This source (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet.3.html) says (emphasis added):

> `inet_aton()` is **not specified in POSIX.1**, but is **available on most systems**.

`inet_pton()` is even better, and available with my original build command in the question, and is described here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html. It does *not* require any gcc feature test macros to include it, and it has more functionality than `inet_aton` and handles both IPv4 address families (`AF_INET`) and IPv6 address families (`AF_INET6`).

See also the gcc glibc one-page user manual. Here is the link to the `int inet_pton (int af, const char *cp, void *buf)` part: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#index-inet_005fpton (emphasis added):

> This function converts an Internet address (either IPv4 or IPv6) from **presentation (textual) to network (binary) format**. `af` should be either `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6`, as appropriate for the type of address being converted. `cp` is a pointer to the input string, and `buf` is a pointer to a buffer for the result. It is the caller’s responsibility to make sure the buffer is large enough.

#### Full example of `inet_aton()` and `inet_pton()`

For my full example code, including error checking, search this file for `inet_aton` and `inet_pton` (recommended), in this file from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo here: [socket__geeksforgeeks_udp_server_GS_edit_GREAT.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/socket__geeksforgeeks_udp_server_GS_edit_GREAT.c).

Example: here is my [`inet_pton()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3p.html) example code:

```c
int retcode;

// ...

retcode = inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &addr_server.sin_addr); // <--- Option 3/3 to set the IP address
if (retcode != 1)
{
    printf("`inet_pton()` failed! ");
    if (retcode == 0)
    {
        printf("The source IP address string does not contain a character string representing "
               "a valid network address in the specified address family.\n");
    }
    else if (retcode == -1)
    {
        printf("Invalid address family (AF) parameter was passed-in as the 1st argument. "
               "errno = %i: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

Comment: @ikegami, thanks! I like that. I added it to my answer and gave you attribution. It works too, and I plan on using it.