# CassandraDaemon.java:911 - The native library could not be initialized properly

Tags: cassandra

please help :)
Trying to start Cassandra 4.0 version and getting this error:

```
CassandraDaemon.java:911 - The native library could not be initialized properly.
```

Had another error before:

```
NativeLibraryLinux.java:65 - Failed to link the C library against JNA. Native methods will be unavailable.
```

Downloaded JNA newer version and replaced manually, so now there is only one error left :)

Any ideas? Already googled everything, TMP dir is executable, even changed it to custom...WHat else can be?

```
openjdk 11.0.21 2023-10-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-11.0.21.0.9-1) (build 11.0.21+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-11.0.21.0.9-1) (build 11.0.21+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

cassandra-4.0.11
```

Answer (score 1):

Linux version is RockyLinux 9, have replaced jna with the newest one, but no luck, glibc also not the oldest one :)

Anyway, managed to sort the problem by installing JNA separately and creating symlink:
ln -s /usr/share/java/jna.jar /usr/share/cassandra/lib

Also removed jna-5.13.0.jar from /usr/share/cassandra/lib

Answer (score 0):

So this error happens because the [JNA library was compiled with a newer version of glibc](https://support.datastax.com/s/article/ERROR-Failed-to-link-the-C-library-against-JNA-Native-methods-will-be-unavailable).

I downloaded Cassandra 4.0.11 on my Mac (admittedly, not the same as Linux), tried to run it, and saw the same error.

> Downloaded JNA newer version and replaced manually

So I did that next. Replaced Cassandra 4.0.11's `jna-5.6.0.jar` with `jna-5.13.0.jar`, and Casasndra started for me.

Which Linux flavor & version are you running on? Try checking which version of glibc you have by following the steps on this answer: [Check glibc version for a particular gcc compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705660/check-glibc-version-for-a-particular-gcc-compiler)

Depending on your Linux or glibc version, you may need to find a specific JNA library. Or it might be worth it to install/upgrade to a newer version of your Linux flavor.